# What will you do in MVC for the webpage component?

Tags: php, templates

I used to put the logic and markup of my webpages in one php file.

However, I learned about MVC. I read an article about the concept, but I am still a bit confused about the subject:

The Controller should handle logic only.

The View handles the layout, the display, HTML.

There should be no logic code in the View.

**My question :**
**could someone please provide me with examples on how to implement a View webpage component (like the header, footer, menu, submenu)?**

In the template, to minimize logic, one could:

```
<html>
<body>
<div><?=$html_of_header ?></div>
<div><?=$html_of_submenu ?></div>
<div><?=$html_of_mainContent ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I use a variable to hold all the code of eg header, It doesn't make sense to me, because I think I would need lots of string concat, instead I was just echo it without MCV.

Alternatively like this :

```
<html>
<body>
<div><? include('header.php') ?></div>
<div><? include('submenu.php') ?></div>
<div><? include('content.php') ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know how to pass data for telling the submenu.php & content.php which catalog I am at. I pass it in session for that ? looks like not too good. also it is not good for error handling.

Another option:

```
<? 
$header = new Header();
$submenu = new Submenu($cataId);
$content = new Content($pageId);
?>
<html>
<body>
<div><? $header -> render(); ?></div>
<div><? $submenu -> render(); ?></div>
<div><? $content -> render(); ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Would this work? Would this not imply putting logic in my view?

Comment: The controller contains no logic. The view contains no logic (only presentational logic). The model is a **layer**.

Answer (score 0):

The view contains no **business logic**. There's a difference between "no code" or "no logic" in the view and **no business logic** in the view.

What is business logic? It's everything your app "does". Any feature your app has. Any "action" your app can "do". For example, that's:

- retrieval of data from the database
- specific actions like "register a user", "send a notification email" or "retrieve business report for the month of X"
- any other such core logic

All that stuff goes into the model. Note that the model is not one specific class or group of classes, the model is anything and everything that's necessary to make your app work. It can be as big and complex as it needs to.

The view only contains code that is necessary for *presentation*. That can potentially also be a lot of code. Views don't have to be dumb templates. Views can do anything they need to do to display stuff. Views can be large and complex if necessary. But they must not contain any code or logic which belongs into the model.

The controllers fill in the tiny rest of necessary glue between model, view and the rest of the world.

There's no dogmatic answer for how any of these component need to look like in particular. The MVC approach simply distinguishes between three logically different kinds of code and how they should be grouped, that's all. If you always keep this in your head, the separation should be pretty self explanatory:

1. The model is "your app", it contains every core feature and responsibility. If you opened an interactive command line and loaded only your model, you should be able to do anything you can do in your app just by calling the right model functions.
2. Views can be exchanged as needed, you may want to present the same thing in different ways. Only put code which concerns the particular presentation and is entirely exchangeable into views.
3. Controllers in web applications mostly act as "adapter" for HTTP requests, their only job is to handle the request, invoke the necessary model actions and invoke the right view in response. Controllers can also be exchanged to adapt to different "input" scenarios; imagine having different controllers for using your app on the web, as a REST API and on the command line as admin interface. Don't put anything other than the code necessary to do just that into controllers.

Comment: yes, I know how to put things in the model, and put all the presentation in the View. But i don't know how to implement the "glue ".

For Example, I have a Model for mainMenu,  it query the database to get the id, title of menuItem. 
I have a view, it contains the page layout and a area for the mainMenu. Then, how do you make it working as a good practice ?

Comment: Again: the view can be as complex as it needs to be. Do whatever you need to do, as long as there's no problem or large code duplication if you ever exchange your view for another. If you need to get certain items for the view out of the database, your view should have access to the appropriate model functions to get the data it needs. You should *not* put that into your HTML templates though, have another function/class which manages the data retrieval and have your HTML template only output that data.

Comment: "can be as complex as it needs to be" Do you menu View can be a group of PHP file, not just one php for view & one php for template ?

I may think about a php for handle the layout, and some php handle the web component, but didn't get the idea how to glue them together...

Comment: Absolutely. The view can be as many files as it needs to. Typically in OOP the view is a class (or set of classes) which does whatever it needs to to get the data it needs, then it renders a separate HTML template file.